# Is it possible to achieve beveled edges with css?

Tags: css

I am trying to play around with borders in CSS, but can't figure out how to achieve the following "boxy" look:

[image]

Is it possible? If so how can this be achieved (don't use dark background as it is there to add contrast)

Comment: I was thinking of :after as well, but rotate3D mhmm I don't really want to use it due to cross browser issues

Comment: or maybe this trick with `:after`: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: Interesting, I'll try and play around with this idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible - using `:after` and some additional CSS tricks with borders.

***Example***

http://jsfiddle.net/EaZ8r/3/

***CSS***

```
body { 
    background: #000;
}

#box {
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#box:after {
    display: block;
    background: blue;
    width: 180px;
    height: 0px;
    border: 10px #000 solid;
    border-top: 15px #eee solid;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

***How it works?***

The main thing here is good understanding how `border` is drown by browser. Check out this example: http://jsfiddle.net/n2nsB/. When two borders meet each other the canvas is split between them, what makes some kind of triangles drown there. This can be very useful, because of two things:

1. First of all, `border-width` can be set separately for all 4 borders, so you can change the angle of split! Check the example: http://jsfiddle.net/n2nsB/1/
2. Second, but even more important: you can set `border-color` equal to `background` to make it *invisible*! Example: http://jsfiddle.net/n2nsB/2/
3. You can set border even, when element has no height, what makes the borders only things that are drown for that element. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/n2nsB/3/

On the other hand, you should also know how `:after` pseudo-element works. You can find a lot of really good tutorials about that on the Web. I suggest this one for the begining: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/

So just combine all that things and get what you want.

Comment: Hey Thanks it works! But I have absolutely no idea how it actually does it, could you explain it in a bit more depth by any chance?